# What happens to Clifford algebra structure and periodicity when the field is weird?

Tags: quadratic-forms, clifford-algebras

The classification of the structure of real and complex Clifford algebras [is well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras). Most sources concentrate only upon that case. [Another resource.](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/Spin/Lecture2.pdf) Also, I'm only interested in nondegenerate forms, at this point, and I'd prefer to skip characteristic $2$ if it complicates the answer.

The interesting thing is the [periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Bott_periodicity) exhibited in their structures as the dimension and signature changes.

But the theory of bilinear forms is well-developed over all fields, so I am very curious what happens outside of the idyllic cases of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$. I believe I've seen somewhere how to prove how Clifford algebras over nondegenerate spaces are all semisimple rings (at least, outside of characteristic $2$.)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I remember right, the only thing you need to reduce quadratic forms to a "signature" is to either use an ordered which contains the square roots of all its positive members, or to use a field that's quadratically closed altogether.

> Is the structure/periodicity of Clifford algebras of algebras over fields described in the last paragraph known?

Alternatively, we could stop caring about general bilinear forms and just ask for a classification of those arising from a matrix with $1$'s and $-1$'s on the diagonal.

> Is the structure/periodicity of Clifford algebras for these particular forms over fields known?

I haven't had a lot of luck with the literature. I could believe it if everything had to exhibit periodicity $1, 2, 4,$ or $8$, because that seems to be the way geometry likes to roll.

Comment: Characteristic $2$ is interesting: the Arf invariant falls out from the structure of the Clifford algebra.

Comment: You may be looking for the Brauer-Wall group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer%E2%80%93Wall_group

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for the references!